# Missing collection information (Parameterized Type) in SymbolTable

Tags: tooling-api

I've just started working with `ApexClass.SymbolTable` from the ToolingAPI.  In the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_symboltable.htm#topic-title), a SymbolTable entry contains `properties`, `variables`, and `methods` which have `parameters`.  The documentation doesn't show a way to get Type information about `properties`, `variables`, or `parameters`, but the API result includes a `type` property for each.

All of the `variables` in my symbol table which represent collections include the full parameterized type, e.g., `List<String>` or `List<ApexClass.InnerType>`.  But all of the `properties` and method `parameters` only show the non-parameterized `List` type.

Example Variable:

```
{
  "annotations": [ ], 
  "location": {
    "column": 49, 
    "line": 52
  }, 
  "modifiers": [ ], 
  "name": "fields", 
  "references": [ ], 
  "type": "List<Schema.SObjectField>"
},
```

Example property:

```
{
    "annotations": [ ], 
    "location": {
        "column": 32, 
        "line": 18
    }, 
    "modifiers": [
        "private"
    ], 
    "name": "sortSpecs", 
    "references": [ ], 
    "type": "List"
},
```

Not sure why it should matter, but I'm fetching these results with Workbench, just to inspect the SymbolTable result.

Is this a known issue?  A bug?  I've been able to find almost no documentation of `SymbolTable` beyond the page in the Tooling API docs, nor any report of this issue.  Is it possible to get the full type info for any `List` property?

Comment: Hey Jason, did you raise the idea as suggested by FishOfPrey? Could you provide the link if you did please?

Comment: @PhilW No, this was research for a possible project that got shelved.  I found that [someone had created the Idea back in 2015](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdk6AUAR/expose-the-parameter-type-listsetmap-of-the-apex-methods-for-tooling-api) but it was archived for low activity, so I didn't create a new one.  If you decide to create it, please add it to https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2361/ideas-that-every-salesforce-developer-should-vote-for.  I'll certainly vote for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a short coming of the SymbolTable API design. I'd suggest raising an idea to expand out the parameterized type information.

---

There is one more complicated option you can do for parameters.
Take the example class below:

```
public class TakesListParameter {
    
    public List<String> listOfAccountNames = new List<String>();
    
    public List<Decimal> amountsProperty { get; set; }
    
    public void doCalculation(List<Integer> inputNumbers) {
        listOfAccountNames = new List<String>();
        amountsProperty = new List<Decimal>();
    }
    
    public List<String> getValues() {
        return new List<String>();
    }
}
```

Under methods you will see `doCalculation` as:

```
{
        "annotations": [],
        "location": {
            "column": 17,
            "line": 7
        },
        "modifiers": ["public"],
        "name": "doCalculation",
        "parameters": [{
                "name": "inputNumbers",
                "type": "List"
            }
        ],
        "references": [],
        "returnType": "void",
        "type": null
},
```

As you observed, the parameter type is just "List".

Further down in the SymbolTable is the "variables" section. In that you will find:

```
{
    "annotations": [],
    "location": {
        "column": 45,
        "line": 7
    },
    "modifiers": [],
    "name": "inputNumbers",
    "references": [],
    "type": "List<Integer>"
}
```

Note that between the name and the line number this is the same input parameter, and includes the full type information.

Unfortunately this won't help you for properties or return types.  As above, raise an idea exchange post out to expand the parameterized type information would be helpful.

---

For reference, anonymous Apex code to get the symbol table for a class:

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
Id testClassId = [Select Id from ApexClass where Name = 'TakesListParameter'].Id;
request.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v56.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+Id,Name,SymbolTable+From+ApexClass+where+Id=\''+testClassId+'\'');
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
request.setTimeout(10000);

HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
System.debug(response.getBody());
```